# Cucumber + parallel_tests. HTML results?

Tags: cucumber

I currently try to implement parallel_tests for our Cucumber + Watir-WebDriver acceptance tests. As far it goes great.

However, we got used to nice HTML reports from Cucumber with embedded screenshots of failed scenarios. Cucumber creates reports as a single HTML file with all the features. But with parallel_tests, this HTML file is overwritten with the last called Cucumber process and thus incomplete.

Is it possible to generate several HTML reports or generate HTML reports per features file?

Comment: what command did you execute for this to work? I'm having issues getting it to wok...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put

```
default: --format html --out report<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>.html
```

in `./config/cucumber.yml`. Whey you run the tests, you will find `report.html`, `report2.html` (...) files in project root.

Comment: Not working for me:

cucumber -p parallel features/IVA_features --out output/report <%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>.html

-bash: %=: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have this out of the box.  What we ended up doing was writing a new formatter.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion.