# Thread synchronization in JRuby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, jruby

I am using JRuby and running my test case in parallel using parallel_test gem.

In one of the tests I need to synchronize few line of code. So how I can synchronize those couple of code in JRuby.

```
loop do
  begin
    mutex.synchronized do 
      read = out.readpartial(1000000)
      result << read
      unless silence
        $stdout.print read
        $stdout.flush
      end
    end  
  end
end rescue EOFError
```

Comment: You could use a [`Mutex`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Mutex.html)

Comment: Wait, `parallel_test` runs multiple *processes*, do you really have to synchronize *threads*?

Comment: Hi Stefan thanks for your quick reply. The problem i am facing is that parallel_test runs multiple process to execute my cucumber features and cucumber generate json file for that result and its used for reporting. But when i am running my test cases, while generating json file multiple threads concurrently writting their result in to json file and json file is not getting properly created and i am getting json malformed error while parsing it. Also added my code with mutex please check it.

Comment: You have multiple threads concurrently writing into a file and you're wondering why your results are mangled?  Oi vey.

Comment: There's a section in the wiki: [Disable parallel run for certain cases (cucumber)](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/wiki#disable-parallel-run-for-certain-cases-cucumber)

Comment: thnx mcfinnigan,  yes its the case.

Comment: @Stefan, i had gone through the link. I am not sure for which cases i should disable the parallel test, since its parallel_test gem who allocates the test case to individual threads on runtime.

Comment: This looks promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623976/cucumber-parallel-tests-html-results