# Is there any way to generate a unique HTML report with parallel_rspec for multiple threads? Not 'n' reports, but only one including all the results

Tags: ruby, testing, parallel-processing, rspec, decorator

Well, so... the last question in this regard was answered 8 years ago ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090410/how-do-you-generate-html-reports-when-running-with-parallel-tests)), and I haven't found any newer questions after that.

This solution is great, but creates multiple html files, so it makes it difficult to create artifacts for all of them and also kind of overwhelming to debug the result of more than 1 thread resulted in test failures.

Is there any way in which you can generate only one of them or just merge them all?

Thanks so much!

I tried adding `@output.flush` at the end of the html_formatter methods that obtain the example result (failure, success, pending), so it directly writes the result straight to the only output that I configured. Anyway, it didn't work as it only showed successful methods and I'm not sure that it showed even all of them.

Edit: this is how my custom formatter looks at this point:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

  def initialize(output)
    super(output)
    @printer = HtmlPrinter.new(output)
    if @n == 1
      puts 'second runner, no need to initilize'
    else
      puts 'first runner, initializing...'
      @n = 1
      @failed_examples = []
      @example_group_number = 0
      @example_number = 0
      @header_red = nil
    end
  end

  def example_passed(passed)
    super(passed)
    @output.flush
  end

  def example_failed(failure)
    super(failure)
    @output.flush
  end

  def example_pending(pending)
    super(pending)
    @output.flush
  end
end
```